# android web call wrong response

Tags: android, caching, response, http-get

I am doing a simple HttpGet and the response is wrong. I did this also in browser and there the response is ok. I checked the URL is the same.

Than I thought it might be some caching so I set the headers:

```
httpGet.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
```

First it worked, but now again it gives me the same old result. It happened the same on iOS but after a reinstall it worked.

Does Android caches the requests on another level?

How can disable caching?

Comment: Did you set the HTML cache meta tag in your document head of your html file: `<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">`  Or you can also try to set the age of the httpGet like this: `httpGet.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");`

Comment: found out that the problem was server side, some problems with the routing and different results was returned